# Difference between Private methods and Actions decorated with NonAction in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, private

in Asp.Net MVC if I decorate an action method with attribute `NonAction` then it wont be allowed to be called by the user visiting the site.
same happens when I make it `private`
So whats the difference between the two and is there a special purpose for which `NonAction` attribute has been made?

For example whats the difference between

```
[NonAction]
public ActionResult SomeAction(){}
```

And

```
private ActionResult SomeAction(){}
```

in the context of asp.net MVC of course I know one is `public` and the other one is `private`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's the only difference. The attribute is used when you want a method that has a signature that would make it an action, but that you don't want to be an action.

An example for a use for that is a method that action methods call to produce the `ActionResult` for them:

```
[NonAction]
public JsonResult JsonInfo(string id, string value) {
  return Json(new { id = id, value = value });
}

public JsonResult GetBusInfo() {
  return JsonInfo("4", "Bus");
}

public JsonResult GetCarInfo() {
  return JsonInfo("8", "Car");
}
```

The reason to make it public instead of private would be so that actions in other controllers could also use it.

Comment: How could other controllers use `public` method marked as `NonAction`?

Comment: @mipe34: By creating an instance of the controller and call the method.

Answer (score 0):

Both works same with action method,you can use them seperately or together.

```
[NonAction]           
        private ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            FEED_TBL fEED_TBL = db.FEED_TBL.Find(id);
            if (fEED_TBL == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(fEED_TBL);
        }
```

If declare it like the above code then when we will try to go to details action method it will not go to it.Rather it will show the error.

```
{{ HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.}}
```

This shows that our detail link on view does found any reference to details action method and our controller to.

Comment: a response of 404 is common. With either of them OR both of them together you would get the same response. What are you trying to point out?